# Do EJB's packaged inside a war only run in the Lite container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, package, war

I recently read `EJB in Action` and i stumbeled upon this text:

```
The Java EE 6 specification allows for session and message-driven beans to be included
inside a WAR module instead of having to deploy them separately in an EJB-JAR module.
When included in a WAR module, the beans run in the EJB Lite container.
```

I couldn't find any info in the specification if `When included in a WAR module, the beans run in the EJB Lite container.` is true.

So can EJB's packaged inside a `.war` run in the full ejb container or are they strictly restricted to the Lite version. Any source on the matter is welcomed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Java EE 6 specification allows for session and message-driven beans to be included inside a WAR ...

This is only partially true! `message-driven beans` are not definitely part of the EJB lite according to the [EJB 3.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) (see *Chapter 21.1: EJB Lite* which is extracted and displayed below):

> ## 21.1 EJB 3.1 Lite
>
> The EJB API is comprised of a large feature set with support for implementing business logic in a wide variety of enterprise applications. However, the full range of API contracts is not always crucial for all
>   runtime environments. In addition, the breadth of the full API can present challenges for developers just getting started with Enterprise JavaBeans technology.
>
> For these reasons this specification defines a minimal subset of the EJB API known as EJB 3.1 Lite.
>   EJB 3.1 Lite is not a product. Rather, it is a proper subset of the full EJB 3.1 API that includes a small,powerful selection of EJB features suitable for writing portable transactional business logic. The defini-
>   tion of EJB 3.1 Lite gives vendors an option to implement only a portable subset of the EJB API within their product. The vastly reduced size of the feature set makes it suitable for inclusion in a wider range
>   of Java products, many of which have much smaller installation and runtime footprints than a typical full Java EE implementation.
>
> An EJB 3.1 Lite application is merely an EJB application whose EJB API usage falls within the EJB Lite subset. There are no special APIs defined only for EJB 3.1 Lite. **Therefore, any EJB 3.1 Lite application can be deployed on any Java EE product that implements Enterprise JavaBeans technology,whether that product supports EJB 3.1 Lite or the full EJB API.**
>
> As detailed in Table 27, the EJB 3.1 Lite API is composed of the following subset of the EJB API :
>
> - Stateless, Stateful, and Singleton Session Bean components
> - Local and no-interface view only
> - Synchronous method invocations only
> - Container-managed transactions / Bean-managed transactions
> - Declarative and programmatic Security
> - Interceptors
> - Deployment Descriptor support (ejb-jar.xml)

The answer for your question

> So can EJB's packaged inside a .war run in the full ejb container or are they strictly restricted to the Lite version.

is also answered by the specification: see bold typed part in the above extract. The Java EE 6 Web Profile is required to support a `.war` file which is also a part of the full profile.

You can find more information in:

- [Java EE 6 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-6.0-fr-oth-JSpec/)
- [Java EE 6 Web Profile specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr316/index.html)